# MYSQL - Syntax for Joining My 3 Tables Correctly

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1064

**Edit2: Chose to separate the queries and collate/handle the information as a whole outside of the database's output. Taking these out in a .CSV format, and adding them into Excel where I'm going to be running the actual numbers.**

Query 1 to pull out orders and desired info:

```
SELECT
shipstation_orders_v2.id AS SSO_id,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_number AS SSO_orderNumber,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_id AS SSO_orderID,
shipstation_orders_v2.storename AS SSO_storeName,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_date AS SSO_orderDate,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_total AS SSO_orderTotal,
shipstation_orders_v2.name AS SSO_name,
shipstation_orders_v2.company AS SSO_company

FROM shipstation_orders_v2

GROUP BY shipstation_orders_v2.id,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_number,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_id,
     shipstation_orders_v2.storename,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_date,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_total,
     shipstation_orders_v2.name,
     shipstation_orders_v2.company

ORDER BY SSO_orderDate
```

Query 2 to pull out fulfillments and equivalent info:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
shipstation_orders_v2.id AS SSO_id,
shipstation_fulfillments.id AS SSF_id,
shipstation_fulfillments.order_number AS SSF_orderNumber,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_number AS SSO_orderNumber,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_id AS SSO_orderID,
shipstation_orders_v2.storename AS SSO_storeName,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_date AS SSO_orderDate,
shipstation_fulfillments.order_date AS SSF_orderDate,
shipstation_orders_v2.order_total AS SSO_orderTotal,
shipstation_fulfillments.amount_paid AS SSF_amountPaid,
shipstation_orders_v2.name AS SSO_name,
shipstation_orders_v2.company AS SSO_company,
shipstation_fulfillments.name AS SSF_name,
shipstation_fulfillments.company AS SSF_company

FROM shipstation_fulfillments

  INNER JOIN shipstation_orders_v2
  ON shipstation_fulfillments.order_number = 
  shipstation_orders_v2.order_number

WHERE shipstation_fulfillments.order_number = 
shipstation_orders_v2.order_number
  GROUP BY shipstation_orders_v2.id,
     shipstation_fulfillments.id,
     shipstation_fulfillments.order_number,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_number,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_id,
     shipstation_orders_v2.storename,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_date,
     shipstation_fulfillments.order_date,
     shipstation_orders_v2.order_total,
     shipstation_fulfillments.amount_paid,
     shipstation_orders_v2.name,
     shipstation_orders_v2.company,
     shipstation_fulfillments.name,
     shipstation_fulfillments.company
```

**Edit: Question marked as answered. I figured out another way to do it that wasn't quite as harebrained. Props to DRapp for getting my brain moving.**

**Original Code is below Wall of Text**

I'm a self-taught MySQL database user. I won't say administrator, since it's just me. I've put together a small database for work - about 60,000 rows and a maximum of 51 columns spread over three tables. I use this at work as a way to organize a fairly disparate sales data setup and make sense of it to identify trends, seasonality, all that good stuff. I work primarily with Shipstation data.

My problem is when I needed to introduce this third table. With two tables, obviously, it's just a simple `JOIN`. I got that working just fine. I'm having quite a bit of trouble setting up the `JOINs` correctly for this third table.

I'm attempting to `JOIN` the data from the two innermost queries to `shipstation_orders_v2` and `order_keys` to the `shipstation_fulfillments` results I have in the third table.

For those of you who don't use Shipstation or aren't familiar with this element of it, fulfillments are in a different category than orders and don't use quite the same data. This is my dirty way of gluing them together so we have some decent, manipulable information on sales and shipping trends, etc.

I am making an internal query from `shipstation_orders_v2` to `order_keys` as a way to `SELECT DISTINCT` the sum totals of split orders. I had problems with data duplication before I built up that subquery. With the (now) subquery and sub-subquery, the duping problem has been eliminated and with just those two tables it worked fine.

The issue is, when I'm making the `SELECT` from `shipstation_fulfillments` with a `JOIN` to the subquery and sub-subquery, I'm hitting a roadblock.

I've gotten several errors while working on this query. In order of occurrence and resolution:

`Error 2013`, lost connection to server during query (which told me I'm doing a full table read on three joined tables, since it isn't erroring out beforehand, but my rinkadink setup can't handle it). I got rid of that one.

Then, Error 1051 for an unidentified table name `shipstation_fulfillments`. To me I think it might be an issue for the query aliases. I am not sure.

Finally, good ole `Error 1064`, incorrect syntax on the first subquery after the
 `SELECT shipstation_fulfillments` arguments.

Being self-taught, I'd virtually guarantee I'm merely missing an element of syntax somewhere that would appear fairly obvious to a well-practiced user of MySQL. Below is my current query setup.

If there needs to be any clarification, let me know.

```
SELECT

`shipstation_fulfillments`.`order_date` AS `orderDate`,
`shipstation_fulfillments`.`order_number` AS `orderNumber`,
(`shipstation_fulfillments`.`amount_paid` + `shipstation_fulfillments`.`tax_paid`) AS "Total Paid",
`shipstation_fulfillments`.`name` AS `name`,
`shipstation_fulfillments`.`company` AS `company`,

FROM
(
    (SELECT
        COUNT(`shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_key`) AS `orderCount`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`key_id` AS `key_id`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_number` AS `order_number`,
        MAX(`shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_date`) AS `order_date`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`storename` AS `store`,
        (`shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_total` -     `shipstation_orders_v2`.`shippingPaid`) AS `orderPrice`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`shippingpaid` AS `shippingPaid`,
        SUM(`shipstation_orders_v2`.`shippingpaid`) AS `SUM shippingPaid`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_total` AS `orderTotal`,
        SUM(`shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_total`) AS `SUM Total Amount Paid`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`qtyshipped` AS `qtyShipped`,
        SUM(`shipstation_orders_v2`.`qtyshipped`) AS `SUM qtyShipped`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`name` AS `name`,
        `shipstation_orders_v2`.`company` AS `company`

        FROM

            (SELECT DISTINCT
                `order_keys`.`key_id` AS `key_id`,
                `order_keys`.`order_key` AS `order_key`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_number` AS `order_number`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_id` AS `order_id`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_date` AS `order_date`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`storename` AS `storename`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_total` AS `order_total`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`qtyshipped` AS `qtyshipped`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`shippingpaid` AS `shippingpaid`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`name` AS `name`,
                `shipstation_orders_v2`.`company` AS `company`
    FROM
        (`shipstation_orders_v2`
    JOIN `order_keys` ON ((`order_keys`.`order_key` = `shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_id`)))) `t`)


JOIN `shipstation_fulfillments`
ON (`shipstation_orders_v2`.`order_number` = `shipstation_fulfillments`.`order_number`)) `w`
```

Comment: one immediate is your last column before "FROM" in primary part of query has extra comma... remove that.

Comment: Done. Code edited to reflect that. Still throws Error 1064 in the sub-subquery `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: What is *"WoT"*?

Comment: Wall of Text. I was fairly wordy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a couple notes... As for long table names, no problem, but you can use alias references to them such as I have done via example ...ShipStation_Fulfillments SSF...  the "SSF" is now an alias for shorter typing yet still makes sense of origin.

When changing column names in query via "AS", you only need the as if your column name result will change from its original as you had in the beginning such as  SSF.order_date AS orderDate where you remove the "_" from the final column name, but also in "Total Paid" (yet I HATE column names with embedded spaces, let the user interface handle labeling things, but thats just me).

When typing table.column (or alias.column), doing via CamelCasing helps readability vs camelcasing slightly harder to read where the brain naturally breaks into readable words for us.

Other issue based on query.  Outer query portions can't recognize aliases from inner closed queryies, only the alias of the subselect as you had with the "t" and "w" aliases.

Next, when doing JOINs, my preference is to read them in the way the tables are within the query listing the first one on the left, and whatever is joined TO on the right.
If went from Table A Join to Table B, the ON clause would be ON A.KeyID = B.KeyID vs B.KeyID = A.KeyID especially if you are going several tables... A->B,  B->C, C->D

Any query with aggregates (sum, avg, count, min, max, etc) must have a "GROUP BY" clause to identify when each record should break.  In your example, I would assume break on the original sales order.

Although this query IS NOT WORKING, here is a cleaned-up version of your query showing implementations from above.

```
SELECT
      SSF.order_date AS OrderDate,
      SSF.order_number AS OrderNumber,
      (SSF.amount_paid + SSF.tax_paid) AS `Total Paid`,
      SSF.name,
      SSF.company
   FROM
      ( SELECT
                SSOv2.key_id,
                SSOv2.order_number,
                SSOv2.storename AS store,
                SSOv2.order_total - SSOv2.shippingPaid AS OrderPrice,
                SSOv2.ShippingPaid,
                SSOv2.order_total AS OrderTotal,
                SSOv2.QtyShipped,
                SSOv2.name,
                SSOv2.company,
                COUNT(SSOv2.order_key) AS orderCount,
                MAX(SSOv2.order_date) AS order_date,
                SUM(SSOv2.shippingpaid) AS `SUM shippingPaid`,
                SUM(SSOv2.order_total) AS `SUM Total Amount Paid`,
                SUM(SSOv2.qtyshipped) AS `SUM qtyShipped`
        FROM
            ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    OK.key_id AS key_id,
                    OK.order_key AS order_key,
                    SSOv2.order_number AS order_number,
                    SSOv2.order_id AS order_id,
                    SSOv2.order_date AS order_date,
                    SSOv2.storename AS storename,
                    SSOv2.order_total AS order_total,
                    SSOv2.qtyshipped AS qtyshipped,
                    SSOv2.shippingpaid AS shippingpaid,
                    SSOv2.name AS name,
                    SSOv2.company AS company
                 FROM
                    shipstation_orders_v2 SSOv2
                       JOIN order_keys 
                          ON SSOv2.order_id = OK.order_key
                       JOIN shipstation_fulfillments SSF
                          ON SSOv2.order_number = SSF.order_number ) t 
      ) w
```

Next, without seeing actual data or listed structures critical to solve the query, I will ask you edit your existing post.  Create a sample table listing table, columns and sample data so we can see the basis of what you are aggregating and trying to get out of the query.  Especially show where there could be multiple rows per order and fulfillment respectively and a sample answer of what you EXPECT the results to show.

Comment: Thank you for all of your input. I'm putting some samples together and continuing to tinker around with it.

Comment: @Grinny, glad you were able to get your query to work.  You might want to post your final answer back in your edited post so others can also learn from your self-learning experience too and how it was finally resolved, not that my answer just helped from guidance.